# FormatException (FormatException: Invalid token)

Tags: flutter, jwt

i have an error when i use Map<String, dynamic> decodedToken = JwtDecoder.decode(token)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPuE6.png)

this is function i use Map<String, dynamic> decodedToken = JwtDecoder.decode(token)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbhPD.png)

i try flutter clean and flutter pub get
plese help me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.